# Python simplifying nested for loops using recursive function or other methods

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, nested-loops

I would like to simplify the following codes:

```
import numpy as np
interval = 20
wgt = list(np.arange(0, 101, interval))

pairs = []
for a in wgt:
    for b in list(np.arange(0, 101-a, interval)):
        for c in list(np.arange(0, 101-a-b, interval)):
            for d in list(np.arange(0, 101-a-b-c, interval)):
                for e in list(np.arange(0, 101-a-b-c-d, interval)):
                    for f in list(np.arange(0, 101-a-b-c-d-e, interval)):
                        for g in list(np.arange(0, 101-a-b-c-d-e-f, interval)):
                            for h in list(np.arange(0, 101-a-b-c-d-e-f-g, interval)): 
                                for i in list(np.arange(0, 101-a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h, interval)):
                                    j = 100-a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i
                                    pairs.append([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j])
```

Eventually, I want to obtain the pairs repeating for loops N times. The number of columns in pairs[] increases with the number of loops.

Can somebody possibly simplify the above code? I know one possible solution is using recursive function, but it is too challenging task for me, beginner. I do not care if your code includes other methods or syntax as long as it simplifies codes.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try to reduce the problem down to its most basic form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is the following recursive function:

```py
def foo(n, wgt, s):
  if n==1:
    return [[100-s]]
  
  pairs = []
  for w in wgt:
    if s+w > 100: continue
    for t in f(n-1, wgt, s+w):
      pairs.append([w] + t)
  return pairs
```

And you can produce the desired `pairs` list with:

```py
import numpy as np
interval = 20
wgt = np.arange(0, 101, interval)
N = 10

pairs = foo(N, wgt, 0)
```