# Simplifying nested for loops

Tags: python, recursion, syntax

I am looking for a shorter (probably recursive) way to write the following:

```py
for x1 in range(10):
    for x2 in range(10 - x1):
        for x3 in range(10 - (x1 + x2)):
            for x4 in range(10 - (x1 + x2 + x3)):
                print(x1,x2,x3,x4)
```

Comment: Something similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64632089/python-simplifying-nested-for-loops-using-recursive-function-or-other-methods

Comment: Did you look at the output? Does it ring any bells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a filtered product. Use `itertools` for that, no need for recursion.

```
from itertools import product

n=10
for x1, x2, x3, x4 in filter(lambda x: sum(x) < n, product(range(n), repeat=4)):
    print(x1, x2, x3, x4)
```

Output:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1
0 0 0 2
0 0 0 3
0 0 0 4
0 0 0 5
0 0 0 6
0 0 0 7
0 0 0 8
0 0 0 9
0 0 1 0
...
9 0 0 0
```

Comment: aren't you forgetting about some possibilities? `combinations_with_replacement` preserve the order, you should use `product`: you can have 0001 but never 1000

Comment: @cards yes it's actually a product, there are 10**4 possibilities, I corrected the answer

Comment: but I think it is still not enough, there are 10**4 possibilities assuming that the index space a fixed size of 10, but it reducing so one should be filter such product

Comment: I didn't get your last point

Comment: for example with your code you will get: `if (x1, x2, x3, x4) == (3, 9, 9, 9): print('not possible!!')` but this tuple should NOT exist in the original problem

Comment: Looks like I read to quickly, indeed one can filter the product but it's not satisfactory for large numbers, it will throw away more and more combinations. I'll think of a better solution with a rested head ;)

Comment: no problems:) seems good! ...just not sure if `sum < n` or `sum <= n` but I trust in your solution

Comment: It is `<` or you could have `0 0 9 1`. Thanks for the feedback @cards I would have been annoyed to leave around a wrong answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some hints to get you going, and then if you get stuck you can ask more pointed questions: To find a recursive formulation, first give a high-level description of what you want to achieve, then see if you can identify the recursive nature of the problem. To do that, you'll probably need to *generalize* your problem.

So let me give you the high-level description of your problem, in its concrete form:

"Print out all 4-tuples of non-negative numbers such that their sum is 4."

I'd generalize that to

"Print out all n-tuples of non-negative numbers such that their sum is k."

Now try if you can solve that task recursively.